# Windows 10 IoT Core and DuckDNS

Tags: windows-iot

Can I use DuckDNS on Windows 10 IoT Core and if so then is the setup same as Windows powershell instructions on their [website](https://www.duckdns.org/install.jsp). I would like to run ASP.NET Core service on my Raspberry 3 and connect to it via DuckDNS address.

Comment: I tested the script linked from duckDNS but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like a standard DynDNS protocol?

The only reason that ps script will not work is because it is trying to setuyp recurring jobs. I do not think you can do that yet on Win10 IoT.

By looking at the powershell file, all it is doing is a webrequest to a URL

```
$duckdns_url = "https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=" + $strDomain + "&token=" + $strToken + "&ip=" + $strIP;
```

You can easily create a windows DLL that you can include in any of your UWP applciations so that it runs in a background thread every x minutes. Heck, it can even be an JSONP call (or AJAX if that url allows CrossSite)

It is very simple thing.

To be honest, it doesn't even need to run on the Pi - It can run on anything that is on the same network NAT and eventually uses the same public IP. So even another Pi with Raspbian, maybe a script on your router?

Comment: Yes after some studying I became to the same conclusion except that I didn't think of using of background thread to do this. I was going to put the script to other Pi but I do think I will use the background thread. It seems that Windows 10 IoT is missing a lots of features in Powershell (maybe coming soon)

Comment: Windows IoT on Pi lacks allot of features still sadly :( But they are working hard on other awesome features the whole time. It is a very new OS on ARM and they have to build allot of stuff from ground up - It also paradigm shift between traditional nix OS - IoT is more like simple to install one APP to do some stuff good and not an entire OS that does allot of stuff.. Good luck!